# Meilisearch Scout TimeOut

Tags: laravel, meilisearch

I'm using meilisearch for a while, but last 10 days, it started to timeout while updating records.

I'm using scout also, every time product is updated, it's sending an update to meilisearch also. I'm using custom searchable and returns the result like below.

My records are like that; (per product)

```
"id" => 1
  "title" => "blablabla"
  "sef" => "blablabla"
  "barcode" => "blablabla"
  "sku" => "1"
  "price" => "118.09"
  "vat" => 10
  "type" => "product"
  "discount" => "169.90"
  "quantity" => 989
  "is_active" => 1
  "categories" => []
  "colors" => []
  "targets" => []
  "interests" => []
  "materials" => []
  "patterns" => []
  "total_price" => 129.9
  "priority" => -100
  "tags" => []
  "sold" => 0
  "priority_5" => 999999999
  "priority_9" => 999999999
  "priority_10" => 999999999
  "priority_13" => 999999999
  "priority_14" => 999999999
  "priority_15" => 0
  "priority_26" => 999999999
  "priority_29" => 999999999
  "priority_32" => 0
  "priority_41" => 0
  "priority_42" => -30
  "priority_44" => 999999999
  "priority_45" => 999999999
  "priority_49" => 999999999
  "priority_50" => 999999999
  "priority_51" => 999999999
  "priority_52" => 999999999
  "priority_53" => 999999999
  "priority_54" => 999999999
  "priority_55" => 999999999
  "priority_56" => 999999999
  "priority_68" => 999999999
  "priority_69" => 999999999
  "priority_70" => 999999999
  "priority_71" => 999999999
  "priority_72" => 999999999
  "priority_73" => 999999999
  "priority_74" => 999999999
  "priority_75" => 999999999
  "priority_76" => 999999999
  "priority_85" => 999999999
  "priority_166" => 999999999
  "priority_167" => 999999999
  "priority_168" => 999999999
  "priority_169" => 999999999
  "priority_170" => 999999999
  "priority_171" => 999999999
  "priority_172" => 999999999
  "priority_174" => 999999999
  "priority_175" => 999999999
  "priority_176" => 999999999
  "priority_177" => 999999999
  "priority_178" => 999999999
  "priority_179" => 999999999
  "priority_180" => 999999999
  "priority_181" => 999999999
  "priority_182" => 999999999
  "priority_183" => 999999999
  "priority_184" => 999999999
  "priority_185" => 999999999
  "priority_186" => 999999999
  "priority_187" => 999999999
  "priority_188" => 999999999
  "priority_189" => 999999999
  "priority_190" => 999999999
  "priority_191" => 999999999
  "priority_192" => 999999999
  "priority_193" => 999999999
  "priority_194" => 999999999
  "priority_195" => 999999999
  "priority_196" => 999999999
  "priority_197" => 999999999
  "priority_198" => 999999999
  "priority_199" => 999999999
  "priority_200" => 999999999
  "priority_201" => 999999999
  "priority_202" => 999999999
  "priority_203" => 999999999
  "priority_204" => 999999999
  "priority_205" => 999999999
  "priority_206" => 999999999
  "priority_207" => 999999999
  "priority_208" => 999999999
  "priority_209" => 999999999
  "priority_210" => 999999999
  "priority_211" => 999999999
  "priority_212" => 999999999
  "priority_213" => 999999999
  "priority_214" => 999999999
  "priority_215" => 999999999
  "priority_216" => 999999999
  "priority_217" => 999999999
  "priority_218" => 999999999
  "priority_219" => 999999999
  "priority_220" => 999999999
  "priority_221" => 999999999
  "priority_222" => 999999999
  "priority_223" => 999999999
  "priority_224" => 999999999
  "priority_225" => 999999999
  "priority_226" => -160
  "priority_227" => 999999999
  "priority_228" => 999999999
  "priority_229" => 999999999
  "priority_230" => 999999999
  "priority_232" => 999999999
  "priority_233" => 999999999
  "priority_234" => 999999999
  "priority_235" => 999999999
  "priority_236" => 999999999
  "priority_237" => 999999999
  "priority_238" => 999999999
  "priority_239" => 999999999
  "priority_240" => 999999999
  "priority_241" => 999999999
  "priority_242" => 999999999
  "priority_243" => 999999999
  "priority_244" => 999999999
  "priority_245" => 999999999
  "priority_246" => 999999999
  "priority_247" => 999999999
  "priority_248" => 999999999
  "priority_249" => 999999999
  "priority_250" => 999999999
  "priority_251" => 999999999
  "priority_252" => 999999999
  "priority_253" => 999999999
  "priority_254" => 999999999
  "priority_255" => 999999999
  "priority_256" => 999999999
  "priority_257" => 999999999
  "priority_258" => 999999999
  "priority_259" => 999999999
  "priority_262" => 999999999
  "priority_263" => 999999999
  "priority_264" => 999999999
  "priority_265" => 999999999
  "priority_266" => 999999999
  "priority_267" => 999999999
  "priority_268" => 999999999
  "priority_269" => 999999999
  "priority_270" => 999999999
  "priority_271" => 999999999
  "priority_272" => 999999999
  "priority_273" => 999999999
  "priority_274" => 999999999
  "priority_275" => 999999999
  "priority_276" => 999999999
  "priority_277" => 999999999
  "priority_278" => 999999999
  "priority_279" => 999999999
  "priority_280" => 999999999
  "priority_281" => 999999999
  "priority_282" => 999999999
  "priority_283" => 999999999
  "priority_284" => 999999999
  "priority_285" => 1
  "priority_286" => 999999999
  "priority_287" => 999999999
  "priority_288" => 999999999
  "priority_289" => 999999999
  "priority_290" => 999999999
  "priority_291" => 1
  "priority_292" => 999999999
  "priority_293" => 999999999
  "priority_294" => 999999999
  "priority_295" => 999999999
  "priority_296" => 999999999
  "priority_297" => 999999999
  "priority_298" => 999999999
  "priority_299" => 999999999
  "priority_300" => 999999999
  "priority_301" => 999999999
  "priority_302" => 999999999
```

Is there any limitation for meilisearch? Even if I send 5 "priority_*" it returns error also. Why? I don't understand that, really. Why it returns these errors?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the status of your [tasks](https://www.meilisearch.com/docs/reference/api/tasks#get-tasks).

Some tasks might have the `failed` status. In that case, you can look at the `error` field to know what's happening.

You may want to learn more about Meilisearch [asynchronous tasks](https://www.meilisearch.com/docs/learn/async/asynchronous_operations).